# Laravel How to handle file upload: Can't save image filename

Tags: laravel, file-upload, controller, store, laravel-7

So I want to upload a picture but it only store its description correctly. The file is stored as "noimage.jpg" which means the filename isn't read. I'm using modal btw. My database is named **galleries** and the migration contains these:

- $table->id();
- $table->timestamps();
- $table->string('upload');
- $table->longtext('description')->nullable();

CONTROLLER:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $galleries=new Gallery;
        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('upload')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->upload('upload')->storeAs('public/upload', $fileNameToStore);
        
        // make thumbnails
            $thumbStore = 'thumb.'.$filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            $thumb = Image::make($request->file('upload')->getRealPath());
            $thumb->save('storage/upload/'.$thumbStore);        
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $galleries->description = $request->input('description');
        $galleries->upload = $fileNameToStore;
        $galleries->save();
        
    }
```

FORM:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">                       
                    
                    <!-- Upload image input-->
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 px-2 py-2 rounded-pill bg-secondary shadow-sm">
                        <input  type="file" name="upload" id="upload" onchange="readURL(this);" class="form-control border-0">
                        
                        <label id="upload-label" for="upload" class="font-weight-light text-muted">Choose file</label>

                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <label for="upload" class="btn btn-light m-0 rounded-pill px-4"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 text-muted"></i><small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-muted">Choose file</small></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Uploaded image area-->
                    <p class="font-italic text-white text-center">The image uploaded will be rendered inside the box below.</p>
                    <div class="image-area mt-4 bg-white"><img id="imageResult" src="#" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm mx-auto d-block"></div>
                    <label>Caption</label>
                    <input type="textarea" class="form-control text-white" name="description" id="description">

                </div>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
//ADD PICTURE
    $('#btnUpload').click(function(){
        $('#uploadModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            data: $('#uploadForm').serialize(),
            url: "{{ route('home.store') }}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', 

            success: function(data){
                $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');
            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
//Image reader to show pic when selected
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imageResult')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#upload').on('change', function () {
            readURL(input);
        });
    });

    var input = document.getElementById( 'upload' );
    var infoArea = document.getElementById( 'upload-label' );

    input.addEventListener( 'change', showFileName );
    function showFileName( event ) {
    var input = event.srcElement;
    var fileName = input.files[0].name;
    infoArea.textContent = 'File name: ' + fileName;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add **enctype='multipart/form-data'** as `<form id="uploadForm" enctype='multipart/form-data>`

Comment: nothing changed file name is still saved as "noimage.jpg"

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, try to do `dd($request->hasFile('upload'));` & check if you are getting true, or you can just show `dd($request);` in the question

Comment: I'm getting this very long response text in **promise: ƒ ( obj )** here's the beginning of it: `<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement(...`

Comment: try to look what you are getting in the $request in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using ajax to upload the file, you'll need to use a FormData object instead of `.serialize()`

```
    $.ajax({
        data: new FormData($('#uploadForm').get(0)),  // use formdata object
        url: "{{ route('home.store') }}",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: false,  // required for
        processData: false,  // jquery ajax file upload
        success: function(data){
            $('#uploadModal').modal('hide');
        },

        error: function(data){
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't add **"enctype"** in form tag.

Change your **code**:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
```

**with**:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: nothing changed file name is still saved as "noimage.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

If this above not working then:

1.install this package by following command:

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
```

2.In config/app add this line:

```
'providers' => [
      // ...
     **Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,**
    // ...
 ],
 
and

'aliases' => [
   // ...
  **'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,**
   // ...
],
```

3.Change Form:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'action'=> 'NameofController@store', 'method' => 'POST','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
                 <div class="form-group"> 
                    {{Form::text('name','' , ['class' =>'form-control'])}}
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group">    
                    {{Form::text('phone','' , ['class' =>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'phone' ])}}
                 </div>   
                 <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::file('image_name')}}
                 </div>
                 {{Form::submit('Submit' , ['class' =>'btn btn-primary' ])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, we are required not to use this form format yet, just the classic php and html style...hehe

Comment: But this method is secure.

Comment: well this prof of ours want us to suffer so sadly, can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can this way to store your file with custom name:

```
$path = $request->file('upload')->store('public/upload/' .$fileNameToStore);
```